# How to implement pagination and live search using ajax in Laravel 8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to implement pagination with live search. My live search is
working but when I click on page number 2, I always see the page 1
data. I don't understand how to implement pagination properly so that
after clicking on other page I will find different data.

Here is my `index.blade.php` where I want to implement pagination and live search.

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('css')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
@endsection
@section('content')

<br>
<div class="br-pagebody">
   <div class="br-section-wrapper">
       @include('include._message')
   <div class="row">
       <h6 class="br-section-label">Doctors List</h6>
   </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 ">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search doctor Data" />
           </div>
         </div>



         <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-5">
             <a href="{{route('doctors.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 35px">Add New Doctor</a>
         </div>
     </div>

   </br>
     
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-colored table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-colored thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Doctor Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>mobile</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>


        </thead>   
     <tbody>   
     
      </tbody>
    </table> 
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_page" id="hidden_page" value="1" /> 
    </div><!-- table-wrapper -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
      {!! $doctors->links() !!}
  </div>

  </div>
</div>

                      
        
@endsection
@section('js')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_doctor_data();

 function fetch_doctor_data(query = '')
 {
 
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{route('search.doctor')}}",
   method:"GET",
   data:{'query':query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    
     var output = '';
    if(data.data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.data.length; count++)
     {
     
      output += '<tr>';
      output += '<td class="center"><img src="'+data.data[count].image+'" style="width:40px;height:40px;"/></td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].id+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].name+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].department.name+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].email+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].mobile+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].status+'</td>';
      output += '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="doctors/'+data.data[count].id+'/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></a><button style="margin-left:2px;" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="'+data.data[count].id+'" data-id="'+data.data[count].id+'"><i class="fas fa-trash">Delete</i></button></td>';
      output += '</tr>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     output += '<tr>';
     output += '<td colspan="8" style="text-align:center">No Data Found</td>';
     output += '</tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(output);
   }
   
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_doctor_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { 
    if(!confirm("Do you really want to do this?")) {
       return false;
     }

        var $element = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id= $(this).val();
       var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
      
      console.log(id)
      $.ajax(
      {
          url: "doctors/"+id,
          type: 'delete', 
          data: {
              "id": id ,
              "_token": token,
          },
          success: function (response)
          {
              console.log(response)
              $element.fadeOut().remove(); 
          }
             
        });
         
      });
    });

</script>
     
@endsection
```

Here is my function in the controller for live search:

```
   function liveSearchDoctor(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $output = '';
      $query = $request->get('query');
      
      if($query != '')
      {
        
        $data =Doctor::
            where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->with('department')
            ->paginate(2);
      
         
      }
      else
      {
        $data =Doctor::with('department')
        ->paginate(2);
      }
}
```

Comment: use livewire then no need to manually use ajax

Answer (score 0):

For paginating you should add `page` to query string. In laravel when you use default pagination you just need to pass `page` parameter to url. It also provides you with more additional info about e.g. what's next page or how many pages are totally.

For technical part of the problem you can easily pass it with jquery your using. And also consider that using Libraries like Datatable can help you write less code.